# chaincode: failed to execute script docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger

I am not able to execute docker-compose script while trying to set up the chaincode environment. Any advices to solve this?

Snapshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rw5s9roTIicUVSY3RFUFdPT2M/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with docker-compose installation at the first place and seemed nothing to do with hyperledger.

Please try to follow [getting started](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBarger I have reconfigured the bios to enable virtualization, and reinstalled docker toolbox for windows 7. I still have problems running the hello world to test. Seems like I still have problems with docker daemon.   
Error message: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rw5s9roTIiWnpOM1JhVUNDZVU/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                           Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not running windows, hence won't be able to help here.